# I have a method in a class but it is not returning values, is it because I'm passing parameters to the method?

Tags: flutter, dart

Im trying to make a class and method to do HTTP requests using Dio

```
class appCommunicate {

  appGetRequest(String url, {headers = ''})
  async {

    if (headers.length > 0) {

      _res =  await dio.get(url, options: Options(headers: headers));
    }
    else
    {
      _res = await dio.get(url);

    }


    return _res;

  }

}
```

And then when I try to invoke this class as follows:

```
          final communicate = appCommunicate();
          final response = await communicate.appGetRequest(_myUrl);
```

Nothing happens, no communication and the app just stops there

Comment: Just a note. Please always specify the type of the returned value and arguments when defining methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dio.get() is venerable for exception. You must add dio.get code in try catch block to handle exception.

```
appGetRequest(String url, {headers = ''}) async {
    try {
        return (headers.length > 0) ? await dio.get(url, options: Options(headers: headers)) : await dio.get(url);
    }
    catch (e) {
        print(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: I put everything into a try-catch block and still nothing comes up in console and no exceptions anywhere.  Everything just goes blank

Comment: Could you please try debugging your application ?

Answer (score 0):

I made a mistake, the class and method as posted above are fine and work fine.

I had another piece of code that was causing the error.  Stupid me!

Answer (score 0):

As it is a `async` type function its return type should be `Future` like this-

class appCommunicate {

```
Future<Response> appGetRequest(String url, {headers = ''})
async {

if (headers.length > 0) {

  _res =  await dio.get(url, options: Options(headers: headers));
}
else
{
  _res = await dio.get(url);

}


return _res;

 }

}
```